The `dd` command always gives me an error at the end of zero-writing a disk
I'm trying to get a bootable Ubuntu installation drive with sudo dd if=ubuntu-24.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdc bs=1M status=progress && sync on a remote CentOS 7.x system with the flash drive attached to the server. But before flashing the iso file, I'm trying to format the flash drive with dd.
The fdisk command shows the following specs for the flash drive:
Disk /dev/sdc: 7813 MB, 7813988352 bytes, 15261696 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

so I tried sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc bs=1M status=progress count=7813988352, unfortunately it gives me the error:
dd: error writing ‘/dev/sdc’: No space left on device

I also tried sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc bs=1M status=progress && sync without count, but it gave the same error.
Checking the disk with the od /dev/sdc command shows there are still lots of non-zero bytes like:
od /dev/sdc
0000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000
*
40000000 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777
*
40317340 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777 000000
40317360 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000
*
40320000 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777
*
40337340 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777 000000 000000
40337360 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000
*
40340000 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777
*
40717160 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777 000000
40717200 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000
*
40720000 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777
*
40737000 051525 041502 030733 000001 020000 000000 000200 024012
40737020 000000 040400 000320 010000 000000 000000 000000 140400
40737040 140400 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000
40737060 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000
*
40740000 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777
*
41317200 177777 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000
41317220 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000
*
41320000 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777
*
41337340 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777 000000
41337360 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000
*
41340000 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777
*
41717000 051525 041502 030736 000001 160000 000001 000200 024012
41717020 000000 041000 000340 170000 000000 000000 000000 164000
41717040 164000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000
41717060 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000
*
41720000 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777

Flashing the .iso file without zeroing is giving:
sudo dd bs=4M if=ubuntu-24.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdc conv=fdatasync  status=progress
2772434944 bytes (2.8 GB) copied, 218.947185 s, 12.7 MB/s
dd: fdatasync failed for ‘/dev/sdc’: Input/output error
661+1 records in
661+1 records out
2773874688 bytes (2.8 GB) copied, 228.46 s, 12.1 MB/s

After which fdisk shows:
Disk /dev/sdc: 7813 MB, 7813988352 bytes, 15261696 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1               1     5417723     2708861+  ee  GPT
/dev/sdc2   *           0           0           0+   0  Empty

and I am never able to boot from the flash drive.
dmesg gives:
[  349.501801] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[  349.501810] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[  349.501815] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Add. Sense: Write protected
[  349.501821] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 2d d2 00 00 00 f0 00
[  349.501825] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdc, sector 3002880
[  349.501886] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 375360, lost async page write
[  349.501951] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 375361, lost async page write
[  349.502075] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 375362, lost async page write
[  349.502201] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 375363, lost async page write
[  349.502327] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 375364, lost async page write
[  349.502453] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 375365, lost async page write
[  349.502582] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 375366, lost async page write
[  349.502708] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 375367, lost async page write
[  349.502833] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 375368, lost async page write
[  349.502958] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 375369, lost async page write
[  349.506165] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[  349.506169] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[  349.506174] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Add. Sense: Write protected
[  349.506178] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 2d d2 f0 00 00 f0 00
[  349.506181] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdc, sector 3003120
[  349.510538] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[  349.510542] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[  349.510546] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Add. Sense: Write protected
[  349.510550] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 2d d3 e0 00 00 f0 00
[  349.510552] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdc, sector 3003360
[  349.511548] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[  349.511555] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[  349.511559] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Add. Sense: Write protected
[  349.511564] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 2d d4 d0 00 00 f0 00
[  349.511567] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdc, sector 3003600
[  349.512562] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[  349.512567] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[  349.512571] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Add. Sense: Write protected
[  349.512575] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 2d d5 c0 00 00 f0 00
[  349.512578] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdc, sector 3003840
[  349.513543] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[  349.513548] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[  349.513552] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Add. Sense: Write protected
[  349.513556] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 2d d6 b0 00 00 f0 00
[  349.513559] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdc, sector 3004080
[  349.514542] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[  349.514546] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[  349.514550] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Add. Sense: Write protected
[  349.514556] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 2d d7 a0 00 00 f0 00
[  349.514559] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdc, sector 3004320
[  349.515547] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[  349.515553] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[  349.515557] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Add. Sense: Write protected
[  349.515562] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 2d d8 90 00 00 f0 00
[  349.515565] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdc, sector 3004560
[  349.516538] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[  349.516543] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[  349.516546] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Add. Sense: Write protected
[  349.516550] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 2d d9 80 00 00 f0 00
[  349.516553] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdc, sector 3004800
[  349.517548] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[  349.517554] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[  349.517558] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Add. Sense: Write protected
[  349.517562] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 2d da 70 00 00 f0 00
[  349.517565] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdc, sector 3005040
[  354.502441] scsi_io_completion: 5656 callbacks suppressed
[  354.502467] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[  354.502473] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[  354.502478] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Add. Sense: Write protected
[  354.502484] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 42 78 80 00 00 f0 00
[  354.502487] blk_update_request: 5656 callbacks suppressed
[  354.502490] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdc, sector 4356224
[  354.502550] buffer_io_error: 169158 callbacks suppressed
[  354.502554] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 544528, lost async page write
[  354.502612] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 544529, lost async page write
[  354.502669] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 544530, lost async page write
[  354.502726] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 544531, lost async page write
[  354.502783] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 544532, lost async page write
[  354.502840] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 544533, lost async page write
[  354.502897] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 544534, lost async page write
[  354.502954] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 544535, lost async page write
[  354.503011] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 544536, lost async page write
[  354.503068] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 544537, lost async page write
[  354.504074] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[  354.504081] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[  354.504085] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Add. Sense: Write protected
[  354.504090] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 42 79 70 00 00 f0 00
[  354.504093] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdc, sector 4356464
[  354.505067] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[  354.505071] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[  354.505075] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Add. Sense: Write protected
[  354.505079] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 42 7a 60 00 00 f0 00
[  354.505081] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdc, sector 4356704
[  354.506067] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[  354.506072] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[  354.506076] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Add. Sense: Write protected
[  354.506093] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 42 7b 50 00 00 f0 00
[  354.506095] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdc, sector 4356944
[  354.507066] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[  354.507072] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[  354.507076] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Add. Sense: Write protected
[  354.507080] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 42 7c 40 00 00 f0 00
[  354.507084] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdc, sector 4357184
[  354.508065] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[  354.508070] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[  354.508074] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Add. Sense: Write protected
[  354.508078] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 42 7d 30 00 00 f0 00
[  354.508081] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdc, sector 4357424
[  354.509064] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[  354.509069] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[  354.509073] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Add. Sense: Write protected
[  354.509077] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 42 7e 20 00 00 f0 00
[  354.509080] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdc, sector 4357664
[  354.510064] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[  354.510069] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[  354.510073] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Add. Sense: Write protected
[  354.510077] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 42 7f 10 00 00 f0 00
[  354.510080] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdc, sector 4357904
[  354.511061] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[  354.511065] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[  354.511068] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Add. Sense: Write protected
[  354.511072] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 42 80 00 00 00 f0 00
[  354.511074] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdc, sector 4358144
[  354.511935] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[  354.511939] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[  354.511942] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Add. Sense: Write protected
[  354.511945] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 42 80 f0 00 00 f0 00
[  354.511948] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdc, sector 4358384
[  358.789202] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is on
[  358.789208] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 23 00 80 00
[  358.795280] Alternate GPT is invalid, using primary GPT.
[  358.795295]  sdc: sdc1 sdc2 sdc3

What I'm doing wrong? How can I get the flash drive to completely wiped out with zeros?

bs=1M status=progress count=7813988352?  You're trying to write 7813988352 blocks, each of 1M, to a disk that's 7813988352 bytes.

(1) You don't need to "format" by writing zeros. Writing the image should be enough. (2) Without count= No space left on device is expected. Your attempt with count= is explained by the above comment. (3) The commands you tried should have written zeros to the whole device. The fact there are non-zero bytes is disturbing. Each of your dd commands should have printed a summary (so many records in, so many records out etc.). What was the summary in each case?

@KamilMaciorowski, thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, attempt to flash the iso file to the driver without zeroing is giving: sudo dd bs=4M if=ubuntu-24.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdc conv=fdatasync  status=progress 2772434944 bytes (2.8 GB) copied, 218.947185 s, 12.7 MB/s dd: fdatasync failed for ‘/dev/sdc’: Input/output error 661+1 records in 661+1 records out 2773874688 bytes (2.8 GB) copied, 228.46 s, 12.1 MB/s

@AndrewHenle, so what should be the write command? udo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc bs=1M status=progress count=7813?

@KamilMaciorowski I've amended the post with additional information, could you please take a look?

Possibly the flash drive is faulty. Your writes without conv=fdatasync allegedly succeeded, because they successfully wrote to the cache governed by the OS. Then there was an I/O error when the OS tried to truly write to the drive. If I'm right then this error should be in dmesg and/or in some log, possibly also shown in tty1 or so. The read with od shows the real(?) content of the drive. With conv=fdatasync dd exits only when it knows the data has been sent to the hardware, so the error is exposed to you this time. Anyway, what you got is not normal, probably a hardware fault.

faulty or fake flash device
